# How to prevent brute-force login into a site - Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel site and have a login form.

[image]

I'm wondering if there is a way to deactivate the form when the user sign-in fail `5x` times.

**Back-End Logics**

I was thinking to keep a track of `loginFailCount` base on email, in my session, and if `it == 5`, deactivate the submit button for 1 hr.

Example

- email : john@doe.com
- loginFailCount : 5
- lockAt : 1523 (3:23 PM)

If the current time is `1623`, I will enable the login button for `john@doe.com` again.

Am I on the right track for thought process ?

Comment: "*Is there a way to acheive that via Javascript Front-End ?*" if you do, then it would be simple to bypass that disable. Remember that client-side code is outside your control - if the attacker has it, they can just turn off the disabling. Also, more than likely they wouldn't be attacking the *form* but directly crafting and sending requests to the server bypassing the frontend.

Comment: Ahh, you made the point, then back end it is.

Comment: Yes? Keep the submitted count server side. Really do the 'blocking' there, visual cue on front end as needed...

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#login-throttling

Comment: I am on Laravel 5.7 not 5.8 yet.

Comment: Generally, for security and data consistency issues, it's best to do the checks on the backend, and display the results on the frontend. You can also do the checks on the frontend while you are waiting for the checks to complete on the backend if you want your site to seem more responsive...

Comment: @kyo doesn't matter works in both. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#login-throttling

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn so basically, this came with Laravel by default ? : https://i.imgur.com/AK34mrL.png

Comment: Yeah, it was first documented in 5.1 though, so I don't know how far back it goes.

Comment: deactivating login because of failed login attempts is inefficient security practice. A better solution would be to add random seconds on your login controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on which version of laravel you are using, login-attempt throttling comes out of the box.

[Laravel Doc - Login Throttling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#login-throttling)

What would be the benefit of disabling the button on the front-end/client site?

If someone is trying to brute force your application he will clearly get around a disabled form submit button? Just curious why not to go for the server-side approach only.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I agree with you, your made your point, I'll think through this a bit more.

Comment: I shall stick with back-end, and will make my owned check since I can prevent it to specific number and throw my owned custom message.

Comment: @kyo you can do both of those things using the `ThrottlesLogins` trait. You can set a `maxAttempts` property on your `LoginController` class and you can set the message in the `throttle` value of your `resources/lang/en/auth.php` file.

Comment: I don't see the line to do that.

Comment: Let's say I want to prevent attempt to 5 times and lock for 1 hour, how do I do that in Laravel 5.7 ?

Comment: You can add `protected $maxAttempts = 5;` and `protected $decayMinutes = 60;` in your `LoginController` class outside of any function.

Answer (score 1):

[OWASP Source](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks)

> The most obvious way to block brute-force attacks is to simply lock out accounts after a defined number of incorrect password attempts. Account lockouts can last a specific duration, such as one hour, or the accounts could remain locked until manually unlocked by an administrator. **However, account lockout is not always the best solution**, because someone could easily abuse the security measure and lock out hundreds of user accounts. In fact, some Web sites experience so many attacks that they are unable to enforce a lockout policy because they would constantly be unlocking customer accounts.

In the same site, there are other options listed, like this one.

> As described, account lockouts are usually not a practical solution, but there are other tricks to deal with brute force attacks. First, since the success of the attack is dependent on time, an easy solution is to inject random pauses when checking a password. Adding even a few seconds' pause can greatly slow a brute-force attack but will not bother most legitimate users as they log in to their accounts.

There are more options available that you can try depending on your expertise and effort.

However if you still just want to continue your solution, @GetOffMyLawn has pointed to the right solution in comments.